# How to unlock a field of an entity in CRM Dynamics 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have an email entity, which contains a subject field which is locked. It's already unlocked in the property option. But still it's showing locked.

Welcome for any comment and suggestion.

[image]

on selection of a 'subject' attribute, I clicked on 'Change Property' and I found it;s already unlocked. Please help how to unlock this. see below
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some fields are required by the system and cannot be removed from the form. Ideally Microsoft should probably have set the field to locked and disabled the option.

Comment: Thanks for all of your support. I wanted to modify the subject field on email entity. Not to hide it any way. I have done it by exporting the email entity, modified the XML file by deleting Subject Cell (<cell></cell>) and then saved it. Then finally import the xml file in import customization and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because CRM excepts that always to be populated (how often do you send an email without a subject?).

There are a couple of fields like that in CRM, I'm guessing you are trying to hide it, probably easiest to accomplish with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for all of your support. I wanted to modify the subject field on email entity. Not to hide it any way. I have done it by exporting the email entity, modified the XML file by deleting Subject Cell (<cell></cell>) and then saved it. Then finally import the xml file in import customization and publish it.

Comment: Could you please arrange to help me for one thing. I want to modify edit filter criteria of an entity view. But this option is not available when I open the view of the entity. Could you please suggest on how modify the filter on view, when edit filter criteria is not available or how to make visible the edit filter criteria. Any suggestion will be much appreciated..

Comment: Post that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a red lock on the field, that is different from business required (the red star).  The red lock on the field means you cannot do anything except leave that field on the form.

The workaround to address this situation is to create a hidden tab.  All fields are presented within tabs.  If you simply create one tab - label it as the "Hidden" tab - then you can throw all of the fields that you want to hide into that tab.

Use JavaScript to hide the tab:

```javascript
document.getElementById("tab<tabNo>Tab").style.display = "none"; //CRM 4.0 syntax
```

or

```javascript
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("Hidden").setVisible(false); //CRM 2011 syntax
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your support. I wanted to modify the subject field on email entity. Not to hide it any way. I have done it by exporting the email entity, modified the XML file by deleting Subject Cell (<cell></cell>) and then saved it. Then finally import the xml file in import customization and publish it.

Comment: I have now stuck with one more thing. I want to modify edit filter criteria of an entity view. But this option is not available when I open the view of the entity. Could you please suggest on how modify the filter on view, when edit filter criteria is not available or how to make visible the edit filter criteria. Any suggestion will be much appreciated..

Comment: I would probably start by asking a separate question.  It will give more visibility to your second question, and it will make answers to the first question less confusing.  Then, I would try and provide as much detail as possible when posting the second question.  For example, are you asking about any entity type, or a specific one (such as the "Email" entity type, the basis of your first question).  If your question is about the Email entity type specifically, I think you are screwed.  The UI specifically says "the ability to customize this view has been limited.  You cannot delete this view"

Comment: I have created a question, please refer the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853671/how-to-modify-the-filter-criteria-on-a-view-of-entity

Comment: One more question I have created, I guess you can help me on this. please help me for the question I have created on the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959924/unable-to-update-contact-record-by-workflow-when-any-email-activity-is-created-i

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a CRM 4 the syntax to do the hiding is somewhat different from CRM 2011 which nairware posted. In [this blog](http://sliong.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/crm-4-0-hide-field-section-tab-with-javascript/) you can see how to hide elements on a form.

Comment: My mistake on thinking about the wrong version.  Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Thanks for all of your support. I wanted to modify the subject field on email entity. Not to hide it any way. I have done it by exporting the email entity, modified the XML file by deleting Subject Cell (<cell></cell>) and then saved it. Then finally import the xml file in import customization and publish it.

Comment: I guess you can help me on this. Refer the question created by me from  the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959924/unable-to-update-contact-record-by-workflow-when-any-email-activity-is-created-i. Any alternative suggestion would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your support. I wanted to modify the subject field on email entity. Not to hide it any way. I have done it by exporting the email entity, modified the XML file by deleting Subject Cell () and then saved it. Then finally import the xml file in import customization and publish it.