# How to modify the filter criteria on a view of entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to modify the view of 'Activity' entity, opened the view and try searching for edit filter criteria option and it's not available on view form.

please see below

[image]

Can you please help to advice me on how I can add filter criteria for this view above. Or how to make it visible the option 'Edit filter criteria' on the form of a view.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Welcome for any feedback...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to do that, but you can do your custom views and for example change the default view for that entity. With custom view you can change everything.

See here step by step: http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2008/08/11/creating-and-editing-views/

Comment: Friend the above is for creating new view for an entity. I want to modify the existing view and moreover I don't know how to create different view (i.e. associated view). Could you please suggest anything related to this. Any information will be much helpful for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: In my opinion there is no way to do that, you cannot change system views. The link i gave you is a alternative you have.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible to achieve.  Pedro's suggestion is your only option.  Create your own Activity view, and then you can create your own filters.  You definitely cannot create your own Associated Views.  Public Views are the only ones you will have a hope of creating or modifying, and in this particular case, you are still restricted.

There are various places spread throughout CRM where you will run into problems like this, where an entity, view, or field is "locked down".  This is the cost of starting with platforms like CRM which are a blackbox that only offer customization up to a certain point.

The problem in this specific case has to do with the nature of activities and the various activity types.  Under the hood, there really is not a traditional record type for Activities.  The Activity entity is really a "pointer entity" (note the internal name "activitypointer").  Activities really point to other entity types (in this case Activity Types) such as Email activities.  The Email entity is more of a traditional entity which you can run standard queries against--but even still that is "locked down".

This additional layer of complexity makes dealing with Activities programmatically more difficult (ex. querying the data, modifying the data via a plugin/SQL, etc.) and, in this particular case, makes even the most basic customizations impossible.