# Unable to update contact record by workflow when any email activity is created in CRM Dynamics 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to unsubscribe email for contact record, I'm done with that whatever suggested in the url below http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crminogic/archive/2009/07/31/crm-quick-campaign-unsubscribe-option.aspx. Everything is working fine for me.

I'm now want to update some of the attribute on the contact entity like 'Lead Opt In', allow to now for 'E-mail', 'Bulk E-mail', 'Phone', 'Mail', when the unsubscribe email is received in CRM. Please see below

[image]

As I can see email activity has been created in CRM, so I'm triggering a workflow below, checking for subject contains 'Unsubscribed:'

[image]

This then must update the contact records which I have supplied in the Workflow for unsubscribe the contact, but this is getting failed saying that **'A record required by this workflow job could not be found'**

[image]

Please try to help me out for these. I have been trying from long time but no luck.

Any way of doing it, alternative way for it also would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is now done, by just creating a workflow for updating field on contact record for unsubscribing email. Workflow will run only when the field 'Send marketing material' changes its value, since the 'Send marketing material' value will be changed automatically when any contact unsubscribe the email.